Multiple views inside Stack and they resize in SwiftUI
I have VStack which which has multiple views inside it and are of variable height. This VStack is placed inside the UITableView. I need to calculate the height of VStack since it resize and give flicker effect
Now I have added geometryReader in the background to calculate the height, but its only called when layout is set.
I don't want to calculate the height of each Text, image and other view height manually. Is there any better way.
I have also tried giving .infity to the height, but it does not work
VStack {
    getTopView()
        .background(
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Color.red.onAppear {
                    totalHeight = geo.size.height
                }
            }
        )
}
.frame(height: totalHeight) // this is set after layout is set
.padding()


You could try using an .onChange handler to respond to changes to the height. If you supply initial: true then this can be used to replace the .onAppear too:
VStack {
    getTopView()
        .background {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                let height = geo.size.height
                Color.red
                    .onChange(of: height, initial: true) { oldVal, newVal in
                        totalHeight = newVal
                    }
            }
        }
}
.frame(height: totalHeight) // this is set after layout is set
.padding()

If your target is pre iOS 17 then you will need to use the (now deprecated) version of .onChange that takes just one parameter and keep the .onAppear:
Color.red
    .onAppear {
        totalHeight = height
    }
    .onChange(of: height) { newVal in
        totalHeight = newVal
    }

